# Mathematically rigorous text on classical electrodynamics.

Tags: reference-request, mathematical-physics

Is there any textbook (preferably not written by a physicist) on classical electrodynamics which gives a rigorous (by the standards of pure mathematics) treatment of (a part of) the topics found in the standard (nonrigorous) physics textbooks such as Jackson? (I don't want to see anything like $\delta(x)$, the text should use distribution theory whenever necessary. Of course it is a shame that Bourbaki did not write such a thing.) Thanks a lot

Comment: (not an answer, but something that you might want to consider) I am in a similar position as yours. I take engineering courses that are mathematically not rigorous. What I do is that I try to formalize the course

Comment: I think if a person is sufficiently mathematically mature , S/he can just formalize the arguments (if the conclusion really follows from the premises). Sometimes you may have to add extra assumptions to make the argument go. In this case realizing that there are additional assumptions more than the ones mentioned in the book adds to your understanding.

Comment: I have felt the importance of this when Ii discover that the assumptions stated are not sufficent for the conclusion to follow. Sometimes I fail though, this happens when there is a lot of mathematical machinery needed to formalize the argument and I still haven't studied them (In this case it becomes hard for me to build them by myself), or when the argument in the engineering  book/course is just total crap and I dont see a way of making it rigorous.

Comment: I should like to point out that the methods of mathematical physics are generally much more advanced than those of engineering (an engineering course is almost by definition not mathematically rigorous), which is not a very controversial statement, and it is very easy to find books treating your mathematics rigorously. However, it seems to me that there are certain parts of physics which are intrinsically nonrigorous, and it is well known that formalizing these parts are a challenge for both laymans (as I am) and experts alike.

Comment: @ooo I Agree.  ${}$

Comment: [Hubbard and Hubbard](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hubbard/vectorcalculus.html) has a section on electromagnetism that might be interesting.

Comment: If you don't like the Dirac $\delta$ function, then don't use one; such a thing can be rigorously avoided. There's no reason that they're necessary in the development of classical Electrodynamics. The delta function notation is convenient for remembering, but the concept is not necessary in the context of classical results.

Comment: @T.A.E.: could you provide a reference please?

Comment: @E.T. Start with potential theory in a classical setting. O.D. Kellogg's *Potential Theory* deals rigorously with Laplace's equation, Poisson's equation, etc. in a classical setting, without any mention of a delta function. Learn about the uniqueness theorems for solutions of various equations. Look up Helmholtz' Theorem, e.g., http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_decomposition . J.D. Jackson's approach can be easily fleshed out without $\delta$ once you have mastered a few such tools. Focus on classical conditions of differentiability and continuity, and careful methods of Calculus.

Answer (score 10):

*Electromagnetic Theory and Computation A Topological Approach*
by Paul W. Gross and P. Robert Kotiuga. Free in http://library.msri.org/books/Book48/.

Also, this thread: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/44973/electromagnetism-for-mathematician.

Answer (score 2):

Any book on differential gemoetry with gauge theory and bundles would probably do the job. Why don't you have a look at Y. Choquet-Bruhat, C. DeWitt-Morette's [Analysis, Manifolds and Physics](http://books.google.ch/books/about/Analysis_Manifolds_and_Physics.html?id=hUWEXphqLo8C&redir_esc=y) (both volumes)? In volume I, chapter Vbis ("Connections on a Principal Fibre Bundle") classical electrodynamics is treated as gauge theory on certain fibre bundles.

Comment: This looks promising, thanks!

Comment: maybe you want something more refined...let me know, ok? A small remark: if this book contains a classical part, it would be good as well: http://www.amazon.com/Quantum-Mathematicians-Encyclopedia-Mathematics-Applications/dp/0521060257 (feel free to check it :-) )

Comment: I respectfully disagree with this answer in the sense that I won't recommend this book to a layman. Actually, I don't know this very book, but from something similar which I have seen in the past, I believe that its treatment surely is very different from classical electrodynamics the way one usually thinks about it. Moreover, to understand it one should first know the "classical" formulation of classical electrodynamics, which is *not* a part of mathematics. A presentation like this one will inevitably hide the physical ideas behind a barrier of highly sophisticated mathematics.

Comment: @ Giuseppe: By a Layman I meant somebody who is not an expert and well established researcher in mathematical physics. (There is a difference between being humble and being an ignoramus, I am ready to tackle this book.) The classical formulation of classical electrodynamics as you call it, is well known to me. @Avitus: the second book is inappropriate.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Can you recommend  a rigorous Classical electrodynamics book for me (I never studied electrodynamics before) ? It would be great if I find the analogue of  "Mathematical Methods in Classical Mechanics" by Arnold

Comment: @Amr: Unfortunately I am not aware of any reference of the kind you are looking for. As far as I know the standard reference for electrodynamics is Jackson's book. (I am sorry for the long delay in replying)