# Which of these things is not like the others?

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, vector-spaces, self-learning, vector-analysis

What's in a name? Well quite a lot, if you're confused enough. I have an engineering-style mathematics education, based on good old hand waving and learning bits and pieces from all over the place. I am now trying to learn mathematics properly, from the ground up, mostly for the love of it.

For functions of a single variable, "analysis" seems to be used almost exclusively for the theory, while "calculus" is the tip of that iceberg, or "how to compute stuff". However, my impression is that when it comes to functions of several variables, the nomenclature is rather more messy. Gibbs seems to have provided the first systematic treatment of the subject in his "[Vector Analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_Analysis)" book, but I would appreciate if someone could explain to me the differences between the following names (and which, if any, are used interchangeably):

- vector analysis
- vector calculus
- multi-variable calculus
- topological vector spaces
- functional analysis

Say I have finished a course on real analysis (e.g. Rudin). Where should I look next if I want to move on to functions several variables?

Comment: See also [stochastic calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_calculus).

Comment: @Lucian To get even more confused? :) Isn't that something I should only be concerned about much later, when studying stochastic processes?

Comment: Well... you said "multi-variable".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two common books you may want to look at are "Analysis on Manifolds" by Munkres and "Calculus on Manifolds" by Spivak.

Multivariable calculus and vector calculus and vector analysis are usually terms reserved for the end of a calculus sequence (usually first 3 or 4 terms in the US, not proof based, basic introduction to stokes/green/divergence theorem, partial derivatives in $\mathbb{R}^3$). Essentially calculus on vector fields. These are often taught from books like Stewart's Calculus, or for smarter kids, Marsden & Tromba's Vector calculus. In Munkres or Spivak's book, you'll see more general and rigorous versions of this (and a few other topics, like de Rham Cohomology if you have time).

Not all books called "calculus" are necessarily non-rigorous (Spivak's Calculus is reasonably rigorous).

Topological vector spaces are simply vector spaces where addition and scalar multiplication are continuous. They are basic structures needed to study functional analysis (see, for example, Chapter 1 of Rudin's Functional Analysis). Functional analysis can be thought of as infinite dimensional linear algebra (say on function spaces) in some sense. You study the geometry of infinite dimensional vector spaces among other things [ often function spaces ], how things converge, etc. Typically, you should have a background in measure and integration (e.g. at the level of Royden's real analysis text or Folland's Real Analysis text) before approaching this subject (unless you're following an applied book for undergrads like Kreyszig). Famous results are Hahn-Banach (related to extending functionals), open mapping theorem, closed graph theorem, Banach-Steinhaus Theorem, Spectral theorems, etc. This is nothing like the prior categories mentioned.

Comment: Thanks. Are the books by Munkres and Spivak more rigorous versions of something like Stewart or Marsden & Tromba? And would you at all recommend reading the book of Gibbs?

Comment: More general and more rigorous. Generally intended for people who have read at least the first 7 ish chapters of Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis (a bit of its flavor is in Rudin, but  the coverage is very bad). Gibbs' book is only of interest for people who are interested in history of the field.

Comment: I will bug you with one more question, out of curiosity. Say I eventually wanted to properly learn electrodynamics from Maxwell's equations (which, believe it or not, I was never taught in an electrical engineering course!). What level would we be talking about in that case?

Comment: You can look at a regular undergrad E&M book for basics (e.g. Griffiths Intro to Electrodynamics or Purcell E&M) for good introductions, which don't require much more than vector calc from the physicist perspective (which is the right way to learn it) and more advanced material from Jackson's Classical Electrodynamics (mostly what you need for this book is a tolerance for pain- rest of it will probably be in a book like Arfken's Mathematical Methods for Physicists). See this thread as well: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/569193/mathematically-rigorous-text-on-classical-electrodynamics

Comment: I know comments like this are not encouraged, but I just want to say thank you for your help. When teaching yourself proper mathematics, going through books alone is very hard; deciding on which books to go for is even harder. So thanks again.