# Mathematically "complete" textbook for undergraduate Electricity and Magnetism.

Tags: reference-request, physics

I am currently studying Mathematical Physics and Pure mathematics. I am taking an undergraduate level course in Electrodynamics, that covers the material in the well known Griffiths Electrodynamics textbook.

I find Griffiths' conversational style, lack of mathematical intuition (in favour of physical intuition) and abuse of notation very off-putting.

I have browsed and looked for alternative texts on both the physics and math stack exchange, but to no avail. I did find [this related answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/569193/mathematically-rigorous-text-on-classical-electrodynamics) which provides excellent resources for Electrodynamics through Algebraic Topology and such, but I need a text that remains within the realm of Vector Calculus.

Comment: I like "Div, Grad, Curl and All That".  I also like "A Student's Guide to Maxwell's Equations" quite a bit.

Comment: @NicNic8 Thanks for your suggestion! I should probably clarify that I already have a solid background in Vector Calculus. Does "Div, Grad, Curl and All That" touch on E&M as well? I always thought it was a more conversational approach to vector calculus, which is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Why not read Griffiths and try to make it more precise yourself. In my experience this isn't too hard. Since you already know some calc and electrodynamics, this will result in a deeper understanding of the material than reading someone else's book. And if you still have questions that's what profs are for.

Comment: @AlexanderHannidesRajapakse  "Div, Grad, Curl and All That" explains vector calculus using electromagnetics.  But perhaps "A Students Guide..." would be better for you.